# Powershell Copy-Item destination is ambiguous

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Assuming that "C:\Temp\first.txt" is a file, is there some way to ensure that

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Temp\first.txt" -Destination "C:\Temp\second.txt"
```

creates file "C:\Temp\second.txt", or else fails? If the destination, "C:\Temp\second.txt" already exists as a directory, I don't want it to create file "C:\Temp\second.txt\second.txt".

Is there a solution that is not vulnerable to race conditions?

Comment: You will need to use the command test-path with a If statement

Comment: Could you elaborate on what sort of race conditions you're looking to avoid?

Comment: If I test the destination to make sure it is not a directory, and then copy the file to the destination, there is a small chance that the destination could be created as a directory after the test and before the copy. The result would be that "C:\Temp\second.txt\second.txt" would be created.

Answer (score 3):

You could run `Copy-Item` with the parameter `-PassThru` and throw an error when the directory path of the result is the same as the destination folder:

```
$src = 'C:\Temp\first.txt'
$dst = 'C:\Temp\second.txt'
try {
    $f = Copy-Item -Path $src -Destination $dst -PassThru
    if ($f.DirectoryName -eq $dst) {
        throw "$dst already exists as a folder."
    }
} catch {
    Remove-Item $f
    throw $_
}
```

Other than that I can't think of anything that wouldn't have a race condition. This also has the disadvantage that the copy would be created regardless, and then removed if it was created in the wrong place.